# If And statement comparing values of same row

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the below code to isolate unique values when comparing range 1 and range 2. I want it to also evaluate the cell in the same row in range 3 to make sure it is not equal to zero. Any tips on how to accomplish that?

```
Sub CompareRanges()

Dim WorkRng1 As Range, WorkRng2 As Range, WorkRng3 As Range, Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range
xTitleId = "Compare Ranges"
Set WorkRng1 = Application.InputBox("Please Select Task ID Range in Invoice Review File", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Set WorkRng2 = Application.InputBox("Please Select Task ID Range in Budget Grid", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Set WorkRng3 = Application.InputBox("Please Select", xTitleId, Type:=8)
For Each Rng1 In WorkRng1
    For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
        If Rng1.Value = Rng2.Value Then
            Rng2.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(254, 255, 255)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
    For Each Rng3 In WorkRng3
        If Rng2.Value > 0 And Rng3.Value <> 0 And Rng2.Interior.Color <> VBA.RGB(254, 255, 255) Then
            Rng2.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Try: `And Cells(Rng2.Row, Rng3.Column) <> 0` instead of `And Rng3.Value <> 0`

Comment: @PortlandRunner worked beautifully, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Portland Runner answered:

> Try: And `Cells(Rng2.Row, Rng3.Column) <> 0` instead of And
>   `Rng3.Value <> 0`